# False positive "variable set but not used" warning in gcc using constexpr/const/static variables in a generic lambda

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm seeing this false positive warning (`-Wunused-but-set-variable`) when using a constexpr, const, or static variable inside a generic lambda, but only when it's called through a template function:

```cpp
template<typename F>
void call(F f)
{
    f(0);
}

int main()
{
    // This fails: variable 'a' set but not used
    // also fails for `const int a = 0;` and `static int a = 0;`
    constexpr int a = 0;
    call([](auto x) { return x == a; });

    // Calling directly is fine
    constexpr int b = 0;
    [](auto x) { return x == b; }(0);

    // Using a regular lambda is also fine
    constexpr int c = 0;
    call([](int x) { return x == c; });
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1MbWcbo8c)

My real code was something like this:

```cpp
constexpr int expectedValue = 123;
auto things = getThings();
auto it = std::find_if(things.begin(), things.end(), [](const auto &thing) {
    return thing.field == expectedValue;
});
```

I found this [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96311) for a similar error which was fixed. The issue I'm having is present in all versions of gcc I can select in godbolt (currently up to 13.1).

My first inclination when I come across a problem is that it's most likely not a compiler error, but the bug report for the related issue makes me think the bug wasn't fully resolved.

Comment: Nice find. What is your question? Do you need a help in opening a bug report?

Comment: I guess? I was turned off a bit by the restrictions in creating a new account on Bugzilla. Seemed kind of weird to me